# Forward all traffic to a host on the internal network with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, nat

This rule forwards port 80 to a host on the internal network:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.3.222:80
```

I want to forward **all** traffic regardless of the port (with `n:n` mapping) to an internal host. I have tried

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.3.222
```

but this doesn't work: the connection timed out.

This rule is part of a more complex chain. My goal is to allow connections to some services on the router (ssh, dns) and forward all other connections to an internal host. The complete chain setup looks like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type local -j dnat-chain

iptables -t nat -A dnat-chain -p tcp --dport 22 RETURN
iptables -t nat -A dnat-chain -p udp --dport 53 RETURN
...
iptables -t nat -A dnat-chain -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination ...
```

I added the same chain to `OUTPUT` to be able to initiate connections from router to internal services:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type local -j dnat-chain
```

**EDIT**

Here is the initial state of the `nat` and `filter` tables:

```
$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT

$ sudo iptables -S -t nat
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 ! -d 10.0.3.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

`lxcbr0` is connected to `10.0.3.0/24`

Comment: I think you should use tcpdump or wireshark to investigate what happens exactly. A guess is that your rule also affects response packets. If I’m right, a `--syn` option might help.

Comment: Do you have rules in filter table? Do you have default policy of `ACCEPT` or `DROP`?

Comment: Default policy is `ACCEPT`.

Comment: The filter table contains rules created by LXC and Docker. The internal network in question is connected to `lxcbr0`. But all filter table rules of this interface have the target `ACCEPT`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding the following rule to the chain:

```
iptables -t nat -I dnat-chain -i lxcbr0 -j RETURN
```